# Does every mathematical operation has an inverse operation?

Tags: arithmetic, inverse

For example, we say that the addition and subtraction are inverse operations like that does each and every mathematical operation has an inverse operation?

Comment: No.  A projection takes a point in a high-dimensional space and places it in a lower-dimensional space.  There is no (unique) way to go back.  There are many many many such operations.

Comment: To have an inverse, an operation (that is, a function) must at least be injective. So squaring and taking cosine don't have true inverses. (We create partial inverses—the square root and arccosine—by limiting the sets on which the operations operate.)

Comment: There are one-sided inverses and two-sided inverses.

Comment: No, Semigroups are algebraic ctructures that are built on associativity, and do not require *a priori* an identity element (or there may be seveal left identitiies, or several right identities, or none at all) or an an inverse element.

Comment: How do you define an inverse operation? For binary operations (such as addition or multiplication) it is not trivial. In fact such operations (subtraction or division) are not introduced. Instead one uses the concept of inverse elements ($-a$, $a^{-1}$), so that the "division by $a$" is in fact multiplication by inverse of $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you take the next "immediate" operation, multiplication, note that it doesn't *always* have an inverse, since division is not always defined. For instance:
$$0\cdot 40=0\Rightarrow  \frac{40}{0}=?$$
Generically speaking (and this is by no means a theorem or an exact statement, only an intuition), "most" operations are not invertible, since you only need one element to not have an inverse in order to ruin everything.

Answer (score 2):

Addition and subtraction have inverses if you only allow a single operand to vary (and fix the other one). But if you think of these operations as mapping an ordered pair of numbers onto a single number, then these operations don't have an inverse.